# CentOS displays NGINX page instead of flask app?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I try to deploy a Flask App on centOS with NGINX. The **Flask app is** served on 127.0.0.1:5000 and is also **accessible with curl 127.0.0.1:5000**.

I tried to keep it simple and removed all NGINX config files in conf.d and just use nginx.conf. This is the **whole content of the nginx.conf** file:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
    listen       80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
}
```

However, **NGINX still shows its default page** and there seems to be nothing in the world or at least in the nginx.conf file to change this. Is there anything in NGINX that still might require reconfiguration or anything on centOS that could lead to the problem?

Comment: Have you reloaded nginx after the config change? `nginx -s reload` for example

Comment: @david yes I believe so, I used ```sudo systemctl status nginx```to restart NGINX and also had no errors after restart

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was indeed open NGINX commands.

After I ran the following commands it worked:

```
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Maybe it helps someone in the future.